# Thanks to the Community

Tags: discussion, community

I know that the post will very likely be deleted. I try it anyway:

**I just finished my (German) PHD project and I wanted to thank the community here for all the help and inspiration.**

The thesis can be viewed here:

> [Thesis](http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/?id=1145031) (Download)

[image]
[image]
[image]

The final presentation containing a animation (`animate` package, see slide 10) can be found here:

> [Presentation](https://bedienhaptik.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/manuel-kuehner-vortrag_final.pdf) (Download) or [here](http://bedienhaptik.de/dissertation/) (Project Site)

[image]
[image]

Here are some of the questions that helped me to achieve this:

- [Beamer Block: White Space When Using Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172602/beamer-block-white-space-when-using-math)
- [First steps with LuaLaTeX and ttf fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/first-steps-with-lualatex-and-ttf-fonts)
- [Beamer: Strange behavior when changing background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153582/beamer-strange-behavior-when-changing-background-color)
- [What causes this beamer block to be slightly offset to the right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164547/what-causes-this-beamer-block-to-be-slightly-offset-to-the-right)
- [Beamer: Using sans serif numbers in math mode together with LuaLaTeX and the fontspec package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155916/beamer-using-sans-serif-numbers-in-math-mode-together-with-lualatex-and-the-fon)
- [pgf/tikz: Making the filling / gap between double border lines transparent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159333/pgf-tikz-making-the-filling-gap-between-double-border-lines-transparent)
- [Beamer: Imitating a beamer block - problem with the width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164593/beamer-imitating-a-beamer-block-problem-with-the-width)
- [Beamer/TikZ/PGF: Applying a key only for one slide (similar to uncover or only)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159491/beamer-tikz-pgf-applying-a-key-only-for-one-slide-similar-to-uncover-or-only)
- [TikZ: transparency causes problems with the color black (opacity, transparency, color model, Adobe Reader)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169762/tikz-transparency-causes-problems-with-the-color-black-opacity-transparency)
- [pgfplots, toks, position of pin edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/pgfplots-toks-position-of-pin-edge)

Comment: My best congratulation! Very nice layout! Except for the nonzero parskip. ;-)

Comment: Congrats ! I finished my PhD some months ago, and the Tex/LaTex SE community is also sincerly thanked ! Your thesis looks great !

Comment: It looks nice. What's the font used?

Comment: http://tug.org/store/lucida/

Comment: This might have the makings of a good blog post - contact Paulo in the chat room, and see what he thinks :)

Comment: Congratulations but would you please consider the size of the files you expect people to load in order to read your thanks? I have a fast connection but my computer struggled somewhat (even in the middle of the night when the local exchange is quiet) and others are not so fortunate. Apologies for being a damp squib but my computer is still trying to download bits of your images.

Comment: I replaced the pictures with low resolution versions. I thought that they are automatically shrinked.

Comment: Congratulations! Although it's nice to send your thesis I think you could add it as another example to [Showcase of beautiful typography done in tex friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought "Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends" is a bit too fancy :).

Comment: I don't get it how to start a chat with Paulo...

Comment: Just AOn the main page, go to »Stack Exchange« in teh upper left corner, There you can find a little »chat« link. Once in there, you can ping @Paulocereda using the @ sign. Paulo will decide if a new chatroom will be created.

Comment: Thanks. I made the mistake that I did not choose a related site.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: See [How to invite someone to chat?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3591/5764)

Comment: @Werner: I opened a chatroom but I am still waiting for a reply. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: Hello there! David just poked me in the chatroom (it hurts!) and here I am! `:)` Congrats for your awesome achievement! I hang out a lot in our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), you can poke us there (including Joseph that might give you the access permissions). `:)`

Comment: I think it would be a great layout for my PhD thesis as well. Could you please share some tips about the template as well, Manuel? Thanks

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: Maybe it's embarassing - what's a blog post? A Community Wiki?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Arora: Sure. Give me a little time. I have some stuff to do related to the thesis (paperwork...)

Comment: @Manuel: Don't worry! `:)` It's an *actual* blog post, posted here: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: Congratulations - I'm printing the final proof copy of my thesis now, so I'm not far behind you!  I have to admit though, your layout is very nice, mine is very plain.

Comment: It's about the content ;). And I admitt that I put a lot of effort in the layout (about 3 months with low priority - step by step). But it's a hobby in the free time. For example the FIRST figure on a new type (liek the staircase diagramm in the post) tokk typically half a day.

Comment: And not everybody likes colors in a phd thesis for engineers...I also had negative comments/feedback

Comment: Haha another haptic thesis great! Mine is here http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra2/766123.pdf I will try to read it as much as my german permits. Nice visual outcome by the way!

Comment: @percusse: Thanks - sorry for the late reply. I was on holiday.

Comment: @percusse I just read the old comments again and saw that you were active in haptics. Are you still working in the area of haptics?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Not as much as old times. Mostly refereeing for journals but mainly control theory actually.

Comment: @user49915 Danke **@user0** :)