# How about Thanks?

Tags: discussion

I have got a lot of fine answers and solutions from members of this forum.
How about a sign from the authors, that I may put into my documents, as a footnote or something like that, just to appriciate the origin?

Comment: Related: [Thanks to the Community](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4461/5764)

Comment: Related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-properly-cite-tex-se-for-its-help-in-typesetting

Answer (score 3):

I always assumed that any posted answer was freely available for anyone to use which also included using the answerer's name in any acknowledgement.